# ExtJS treepanel not getting real children items

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have a treepanel in `ExtJS 4.2.1.`

The tree data is shown in the panel but everytime I expand a node, I get the same information below the node and so to the infinite.

> I'm not getting the real children items. You can appreciate that the json response has children for the parent nodes but somehow everytime I expand one node, an ajax call to my service is done and thus I get again all the tree data structure.

This is my json:

```
[
    {
      "text": "QUALITY AREA",
      "cls": null,
      "expanded": false,
      "checked": false,
      "leaf": false,
      "children": [
        {
          "text": "JUNIOR A",
          "cls": null,
          "expanded": false,
          "checked": false,
          "leaf": true,
          "children": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "HUMAN RESOURCES",
      "cls": null,
      "expanded": false,
      "checked": false,
      "leaf": false,
      "children": [
        {
          "text": "SENIOR C",
          "cls": null,
          "expanded": false,
          "checked": false,
          "leaf": true,
          "children": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "IT DEPARTMENT",
      "cls": null,
      "expanded": false,
      "checked": false,
      "leaf": false,
      "children": [
        {
          "text": "JUNIOR E",
          "cls": null,
          "expanded": false,
          "checked": false,
          "leaf": true,
          "children": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "TRAINING",
      "cls": null,
      "expanded": false,
      "checked": false,
      "leaf": false,
      "children": [
        {
          "text": "JUNIOR F",
          "cls": null,
          "expanded": false,
          "checked": false,
          "leaf": true,
          "children": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "BENEFITS & COMP",
      "cls": null,
      "expanded": false,
      "checked": false,
      "leaf": false,
      "children": [
        {
          "text": "SENIOR D",
          "cls": null,
          "expanded": false,
          "checked": false,
          "leaf": true,
          "children": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "ADMIN",
      "cls": null,
      "expanded": false,
      "checked": false,
      "leaf": false,
      "children": [
        {
          "text": "CHIEF A",
          "cls": null,
          "expanded": false,
          "checked": false,
          "leaf": true,
          "children": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

This is my treepanel:

```
{
                xtype: 'treepanel',
                itemId: 'treepaneltest',
                store: store,
                rootVisible: false,
                useArrows: true,
                frame: true,
                title: 'Check Tree',
                width: 500,
                height: 250,

            }
```

Do I have to change something in my `json`?

Comment: You need to set `loaded: true`, otherwise it tries to load again when you expand the node.

Comment: Where I have to set that property?

Comment: Add 'loaded:true' property in your json like 'checked'

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the store.

Ideally the tree store should look like this as stated below.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Hierarchies',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore', 
    model : 'MyApp.model.Hierarchy',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'path-to-json-file.json',
    },

    root: {
       text: 'Root',
       id: 'root',
       iconCls: 'cls',
       expanded: false,
    }
```

});